# Performing a log-in POST request to a Wordpress site, via Nodejs

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to create log-in functionality to "old school" session/cookie based sites, from Nodejs. What i want to do, is basically  to perform the log in, create the appropriate cookie and then use it in the subsequent requests to the private pages of that site.

Currently i'm trying the [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) library. I'm experimenting against a standard, clean WP site. This is the code:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append('log', 'admin');
form.append('pwd', 'admin');
form.submit('https://somesite.com/wp-login.php',((err,res)=> 
{
 console.log(res.statusCode)
}))
```

I'm getting 403 status, even though the username and password are correct. When looking at the entire response object, i can't really find anything useful, being that i aint sure what to look for.

Is there anything else, that needs to come with that request? Some headers perhaps? I see in the dev-tools that the browser sends various headers, like: 
cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check
Can any of this be relevant?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to include the **method** in your request. Try modifying your code like this:

```
var FormData = require('form-data')
var form = new FormData()
var options = {
"url":"https://somesite.com/wp-login.php",
"auth":{
    "user":"admin",
    "password":"admin"
},
"method":"POST"
}
form.submit(options, (err,res) => 
{
  console.log(res.statusCode)
})
```

Also, a 403 error means the request is forbidden. So, even though your credentials are correct, make sure you have permissions to perform a Post request on the site you are trying on.